# Determine the algebraic structure

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

> let there be:
>
> 1. $(\mathbb{N},*); a*b=a+b+2$
> 2. $(\mathbb{Z},*); a*b=a+b+2$

1. We have a set and a $F:X\times X\rightarrow X$ so we have an algebraic structure let check if there are
   a.associative, b.identity element, c.inverse element, d. commutativity

associative: $(a*b)*c=(a+b+2)*c=(a+b+2)+c+2$
because we are in $\mathbb{N}$ and the addition operation we know that it is associative and commutative so $(a+b+2)+c+2=a+(b+c+2)+2=a*b*c$
So associative is fulfilled

identity element: we need to prove that there is $i\in(\mathbb{N},*); i*b=b*i=b$
let assume there is $i*b=b\iff i+b+2=b$ but because $i,b\in \mathbb{N}$ $i+b+2>b$ and therefore $i*b=b*i\neq b$

So $(\mathbb{N},*); a*b=a+b+2$ is a semigroup

2. We prove that  $(\mathbb{N},*); a*b=a+b+2$ is a semigroup so we will look for an identity element:

that is $i*b=b*i=b\iff i+b+2=b \iff $i=-2$ so there is an identity element

inverse element: We need to find $a$ such that a+b+2=-2 for all $a,b\in (\mathbb{R},*)$ that is $a+b=-4\iff a=-(b+4)$ because there is such $a$ for all selection of $b$ this term is fulfilled.

commutativity: $a*b\iff a+b+2\iff b+a+2\iff b*a$ that is because a,b\in \mathbb{R} and addition is commutative.

So $(\mathbb{Z},*); a*b=a+b+2$ is an abelian group

Is the proof valid?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. We can verify it directly:

- Since we are in $\mathbb{Z}$, $*$ is well-defined.
- **Associativity and Commutativity:** Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is a group, we have $$x*(y*z) = x*(y+z+2) = x + (y+z+2) + 2 = (x+y+2) + z + 2 = (x*y)*z$$ $$x*y = x + y + 2 = y + x + 2 = y*x.$$
- **Identity:** Let $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. Note that $x*(-2) = x + 2 - 2 = x$. Therefore, $(-2)$ is the identity of $(\mathbb{Z},*)$.
- **Inverse:** For each $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, take $y = -x-4$. Then $x*y = x + (-x-4) + 2 = -2$. Therefore $x^{-1} = -x-4$.

Hence, $(\mathbb{Z}, *)$ is an abelian group.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ Any set bijection $\,h\,:\,G'\to G\,$ serves to [transport the algebraic structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+transport+structure) of $\,(G,+,0),$ to $\,(G',\oplus,0') \,$ by defining the operations in $\,G'\,$ to make $\,h\,$ be a (semi)group isomorphism, so

$$\begin{align} &a \oplus b\, =\ h^{-1}(h(a) + h(b)),\quad 0' = h^{-1}(0)\\  
\end{align}\qquad \qquad$$

Yours is simply the special case $\ h(x) = x+2\ $ thus  $\,a\oplus b = (a+2)+(b+2)-2 = a+b+2.\,$   This viewpoint eliminates all of the tedious calculations.